# Activating context-param based on maven profile

Tags: maven

devI am trying to set the value of a context param using maven profile.
Say I have the following boolean Ctx param in **WEB-INF/web.xml**:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>EMAIL_DOCS</param-name>
    <param-value>${email.docs}</param-value>
</context-param>
```

I want to control that value based on maven profile.
So I added the value to my profile's application.properties:

In **src/main/config/dev/application.properties**

```
...
email.docs=true
...
```

and I added the following plugin to my **pom.xml**

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <filteringDeploymentDescriptors>true</filteringDeploymentDescriptors>
        <webResources>
          <resource>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>**/web.xml</include>
            </includes>
          </resource>
        </webResources>
        <warSourceDirectory>src/main/webapp</warSourceDirectory>
        <webXml>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml</webXml>
   </configuration>
</plugin>
```

My profile specific **application.properties** are read via this plugin:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>initialize</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>read-project-properties</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <files>
                    <file>${profile.resources}/application.properties</file>
                </files>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

In which the **${profile.resources}** is defined in the maven profile:

```
 <profile>
    <id>dev</id>
    <properties>
        <env>integration</env>
        <profile.resources>src/main/config/dev</profile.resources>
    </properties>
    <activation>
        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
    </activation>
</profile>
```

I did the above based on similar questions and few recommendation, but nothing worked for me so far. I am not sure what I am missing here? 
(I am using maven v3.2.2)

Comment: I made a simple project with your config and I can't reproduce the problem. I ran `mvn clean install` then unzipped the WAR and looked at the `web.xml`. It was correctly filtered.

Comment: @Tunaki - I confirm it is in the war file. I was actually running the application using maven command line and for somehow I expected a run-time substitution of the context parameter, I didn't realize it is a compile time static substitution. Thanks for pointing out that to me. I would accept it an answer if you put it in proper "Answer" reply.

Comment: It is strange that running the server using maven command (on jetty) doesn't recognize that plugin?

Comment: What exact Maven command did you ran?

Comment: mvn clean install liquibase:update jetty:run